# python regex and sort data

Tags: python

111111|1234|99|777
222222/17/4321/222
333333_333_3333_33
444444-444-44-4444
555555 | 55 | 5555 | 555

how to sort to this result to this:

111111|1234|99|777
222222|4321|17|222
333333|3333|33|333
444444|4444|44|444
555555|5555|55|555

```
>>> s = '111111|1234|99|777\n222222/17/4321/222\n333333_333_3333_33\n444444-444-44-4444\n555555 | 55 | 5555 | 555'
>>> p = re.compile(r'\d{6}[\||/|_|\-](?:\d{4}|\d{3}|\d{2})[\||/|_|\-](?:\d{4}|\d{3}|\d{2})[\||/|_|\-](?:\d{4}|\d{3}|\d{2})')
>>> print re.sub('[/|_-]','|',s)
111111|1234|99|777
222222|17|4321|222
333333|333|3333|33
444444|444|44|4444
555555 | 55 | 5555 | 555
```

and ,how to print \1 \2 in python like sed ?

```
root@localhost:~# echo abc | sed -r 's/(a)(b)c/\1\2/'
ab
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With python and `re` module it is indeed possible to use groups and to match the content of the group i with `\i`. However, for your application I suggest you to use more readable regular expressions to find numbers having exactly 6, 4, 3 and 2 digits. Then you can re-arrange them to produce the expected output, as follows in only two lines of code:

```
import re

s = '111111|1234|99|777\n222222/17/4321/222\n333333_333_3333_33\n444444-444-44-4444\n555555 | 55 | 5555 | 555'

interm = [re.findall('\D('+i+')\D', s) for i in ('\d{6}','\d{4}','\d{2}','\d{3}')]
result = "\n".join(["|".join(line) for line in list(zip(*interm))])

print(result)
# 111111|1234|99|777
# 222222|4321|17|222
# 333333|3333|33|333
# 444444|4444|44|444
# 555555|5555|55|555
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = theString.split('\n')

for line in lines:
    print sorted(re.findall(r"[\w]+", line),reverse=True)
```

I assume you know bit of python and can store it in some other variable.

To skip `\` delimiter you just use it like `\\` in Python(in programming languages in general).